# How to pass an Observable identifier to mergeMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

There is a list of observables of various types and I want to monitor their outputs using mergeMap.
That part is clear using this example code:

```
export class TestClass {

  test() {

    const observableA = of(1, 2, 3);
    const observableB = of(7, 3, 6);
    const observableC = of('A', 'B', 'C');
    const observableD = of(true, true, false);
    const observableE = of(false, true, false);
    // etc...

    const observablesList = [
      observableA,
      observableB,
      observableC,
      observableD,
      observableE
    ]

    from(observablesList).pipe(
      mergeMap(o => o)
    ).subscribe(v => this.handleValue(v));

  }
  private handleValue(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }
```

Here we get a nice output of all values as listed:
1, 2, 3, 7, 3, 6, A, B, C, true, true, false, false, true, false

The question is how to pass the array index or an identifier of the Observable to the function *handleValue(val)* so it could be written like this:

```
  private handleValue(val, index: number) {
    console.log(index, ' - ', val);
  }
```

and would get output something like this:

0 - 1, 0 - 2, 0 - 3,

1 - 7, 1 - 3, 1 - 6,

2 - A, 2 - B, 2 - C,

3 - true,  3 - true, 3 - false,

4 - false, 4 - true, 4 - false

or:

```
  const observablesListB: {[name: string]: Observable<any>}[] =
  [
      {'obsA': observableA},
      {'obsB': observableB},
      {'obsC': observableC},
      {'obsD': observableD},
      {'obsE': observableE}
  ];


  from(observablesList).pipe(
    mergeMap(o => o)
  ).subscribe(v => this.handleValue(v, name));

  private handleValue(val, name: string) {
    console.log(name, ' - ', val);
  }
```

and would get output something like this:

'obsA' - 1, 'obsA' - 2, 'obsA' - 3,

'obsB' - 7, 'obsB' - 3, 'obsB' - 6,

'obsC' - A, 'obsC' - B, 'obsC' - C,

'obsD' - true,  'obsD ' - true, 'obsD' - false,

'obsE' - false, 'obsE ' - true, 'obsE' - false

I am not clear how to reference the index (or id of the Observable) in the portion of:

```
mergeMap(o => ...)
```

or

```
.subscribe( ...
```

or whatever the right syntax should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the offical doc https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap
The 2nd argument is the index

```
mergeMap<T, R, O extends ObservableInput<any>>(project: (value: T, index: number) => O, resultSelector?: number | ((outerValue: T, innerValue: ObservedValueOf<O>, outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number) => R), concurrent: number = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY): OperatorFunction<T, ObservedValueOf<O> | R>
```

and it returns Observed value.

So given that we can do this to acheive the result you are looking for:

```
from(observablesList).pipe(
  mergeMap((o,i) => o.pipe(map((obj, index) => ({index: i, obj})))),
).subscribe(v => this.handleValue(v));

private handleValue(val) {
  console.log(val.index, ' - ', val.obj);
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-q379af

Comment: can you please review line:   o.pipe(map((obj, index) => ({index: i, obj})))), I am getting error "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)"

Comment: @Felix That's just for typed checking, if you want to get rid of that change that line to: `mergeMap((o: Observable<number>,i) => o.pipe(map((obj) => ({index: i, obj})))),`

Comment: Fantastic. Appreciated.